# What is the Ubuntu equivalent of the Windows Start Menu?

Tags: unity

Is there an equivalent of the Windows "Start Menu" in Ubuntu from where all installed programs can be easily accessed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Equivalent of windows start menu in Ubuntu is **Dash**. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> key (AKA <kbd>[image: Windows]</kbd> key on a Windows-style keyboard) on the keyboard to open up dash. There you can search for installed applications, document, directories and also you can search for online materials (like games, musics, news, etc).

[image: Dash]

You can directly access the application lens by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (ie: <kbd>[image: Windows]</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>). Through that you can access installed, recently used applications.

Comment: I'm curious, what are all those hard drives?

Comment: these are my hard-drive partition.I nearly have 8 ntfs partitions.

Comment: Why so many? And why NTFS?

Answer (score 10):

[Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28user_interface%29), the default UI since Ubuntu 11.04, has this wonderful *Dash* desktop search utility. You can access Dash by hitting the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (aka   <kbd>[image: WindowsKey]</kbd>   key in Windows keyboard).

At the bottom of the Dash, click the *application* lens among others, as shown in the snapshot (in *Ubuntu 12.04* you can directly access this using <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>):

[image: dash1]

Click "***Installed: See ... more results***" to view a menu list of all installed applications.

[image: dash2]

Click to launch the application you want. Use arrow keys or the scroll bar to browse for more application down the list.

[image: dash3]

But the *Dash* is not limited to this... There's much more, and is always getting better!

---

If you want a more Windows like panel and menus, try installing UI's like *[Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/)* by Linux Mint, *Classic gnome* in [gnome3](http://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/) by [GNOME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_GNOME_Project)

Answer (score 4):

For those interested in the XP-style Start Menu on  Ubuntu , there is `classic menu indicator`  ( which originally was meant to mimic old Gnome menu , which was in Ubuntu way before Unity Dash came around )

[image]

It's written by Florian Diesch , one of the esteemed members of AskUbuntu community and is available for installation via

```
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```